# Can I load Powershell AD Module as another user?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-ise

I have a script that I use to automate AD and Office 365 account provisioning.
Everything is working just fine.

The only "problem" is that I have a regular domain account and another account which is a Domain Admin.

Is there any way I can load and execute the AD module as another user?
So that I just receive a Credentials prompt, login with my Domain Admin account and the script continues.

Right now I just run the Powershell Console as another user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load a whole module as another user however you can run individual commands.

For example:

```
# Load ActiveDirectory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Save creds securely for this session
$admin = Get-Credential

# Run cmdlet as the admin user
New-ADUser -Credential $admin

# Pull user as the admin user
Get-ADUser -Credential $admin
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if the cmdlet supports the -Credential parameter, if it does not you'll have to run PowerShell in a context where the correct credentials are used.